# ThymeLeaf in Spring Boot Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to configure a simple controller:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public Config(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);

    }
```

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class ControllerPeople {

    private final PersonDAO personDAO;

    @Autowired
    public ControllerPeople(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.personDAO = personDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return "people/test";
    }

    @GetMapping()
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("people", personDAO.index());
        return "people/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", personDAO.getPeople());
        return "people/show";
    }

}
```

When the application start I'm receiving this message:

```
2024-03-03T15:40:59.935+03:00  WARN 9616 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
```

And when I'm tring to move to localhost URL I'm receiving this exception

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/views/people/index.html]")
> at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:649) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]

If I understand it correctly in this rows in config I'm showing when find out my view or problem isn't here

```
templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
```

And my view just in case.

I was trying to create another testing views and move views to `resources/templates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j69Ra.png)

I just added "WEB-INF" directory to "webapp" and it works in my case. Maybe it speciality configuration in Spring Boot maybe someone can explain it to me

Comment: WEB-INF directory is where Thymeleaf looks for all the files it needs to produce outgoing HTML,  e.g. templates. The WEB-INF folder is part of the Java Servlet spec.  I am pretty sure you can configure Thymeleaf to look elsewhere for the templates.